# Executar uma função em dois elementos diferentes sem um afetar o outro

Tags: javascript, wordpress, jquery-toggleclass

Ao clicar no botão "Ver Mais" preciso fazer com que a div contendo o texto da postagem vá se expandindo, se afetar a div ao lado.
Tentei usar `toggleClass()` porém os dois abrem ao mesmo tempo, ou usando uma id somente o primeiro abre.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('#btn-open-post').click(function(event) {
          $('#post-collapse').toggleClass('post-collapse');
        });
      });
```

html

```
     <div class="blog">
        <h2 class="blog-latest">últimas do blog</h2>
           <div class="row">
              <?php echo do_shortcode( '[dois_ultimos]' ); ?>
           </div>
           <a href="/blog/" class="all-posts">ver todas</a>
        </div>
     </div>
```

php

```
function dois_ultimos_posts()
{
    global $post;

    $html = "";

    $dois_ultimos = new WP_Query( array(
         'post_type' => 'post',
         'posts_per_page' => 2
    ));

    if( $dois_ultimos->have_posts() ) : while( $dois_ultimos->have_posts() ) : $dois_ultimos->the_post();
             $html .= "<div class='col-md-6 post-home'  >";
         $html .= "<a href=\"" . get_permalink() . "\" class=\"post-permalink\"> <h3 class='post-title'>" . get_the_title() . " </h3>" . "</a>";
         $html .= "<p class='post-resume' id='post-collapse'>" . get_the_content() . "</p>";
         $html .= "<button id='btn-open-post' class='btn-open-post' id=\"" .get_the_ID() . "\" >Ver mais</button> ";
         $html .= "<div class='overlay-blog-post'>&nbsp;</div> ";
         $html .= "</div>";
    endwhile; endif;

    return $html;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar o `$(this)` dentro da chamada do evento de click para pegar exatamente o botão que foi clicado. A partir daí você pode buscar o elemento "irmão" do botão, que seria o elemento `#post-collapse`, e então aplicar o toggleClass. Lembrando que se você colocar dois ids iguais na mesma página, somente será aplicado a um dos elementos, pois o valor do atributo id deve ser único, tente com uma classe.

Seria algo mais ou menos assim:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#btn-open-post').click(function(event) {
    $(this).prev('#post-collapse').toggleClass('post-collapse');
  });
});
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, Simão!

Comment: Deu certo, Luan?

Comment: Eu fiz alguns ajustes mas usei o $(this) e agora tá funcionando.